# VBA Macros: Want to find last used row of a particular column in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to get the last row of a particular column(sample C) in Excel and using VBA macros so that I can paste the data from Workbook 1 to workbook 2 "C" Columns. Below is the Sample code for your reference where I tried to print the number of used line from Column C. I have tried multiple way to get the last row of C columns but failed to achieve that.

```
Sub CopyData()
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim lCopyLastRow As Long
Dim lDestLastRow As Range
Dim last As Long

Set ws1 = Workbooks("u_change_outage_mapping.xlsx").Worksheets("Raw")
Set ws2 = Workbooks("Checker_20230119-20220125_V1.xlsx").Worksheets("Checker(Combined)")

lCopyLastRow = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
last = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row


Set lDestLastRow = ws2.Range("T1").CurrentRegion


Dim lastRow As Long

lastRow = lDestLastRow.Rows(lDestLastRow.Columns.Count).Column




Debug.Print lCopyLastRow
Debug.Print last
Debug.Print lastRow
End Sub
```

Comment: if you want rows: lastRow = lDestLastRow.Rows(lDestLastRow.Rows.Count).Row

Comment: The command `last = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row` should give you the last used row of column C of ws2. What do you get instead?

Comment: Thanks I tried it was hlpfull

Comment: I had a problem with excel sheet it self which i have rectified and the script is working fine.